# Logitech Media Server web interface won't open on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: interface, logitech

I always worked on Microsoft Windows (latest one was Windows 7), but changed to Linux one year ago.

I used to run Logitech Media Server on Windows and also on Lubuntu without any problem. Smoothly installed.

Several months ago, I changed to Ubuntu 14.04 (because no more updates on Lubuntu version I had) and again installed the Logitech Media Server. Checked that the service is indeed running. But I'm not able to open the web interface on my localhost port 9000. "Not available."

I read on the Internet that perhaps the 32-bit version had to do with it so now I installed the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04. But remains the same. Is there anything I overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mediacenter version 7.7 it might be a problem with the perl version in 14.04. Installing version 7.8.0 might help. I did the trick for me.

see [link](http://blog.janjonas.net/2014-07-02/ubuntu_14_04-lts-install-logitech-mediaserver_7_8) for the solution
and [this](http://forums.slimdevices.com/showthread.php?101147-Ubuntu-14-04-%28Trusty-Tahr%29-problems-Logitech-Media-Server-died-Restarting) for more details